# type narrowing not work if type is specified?

Tags: crystal-lang

```
class Foo
  def initialize(@foo : String | Nil)
  end
  def foo
    @foo
  end
end

a = Foo.new "213"
if !a.foo.nil?
  puts a.foo, typeof(a.foo)
end
```

get output of

```
213
(String | Nil)
```

but shouldn't type of a.foo be narrowed to String? Is this another design limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `@foo` doesn't change. Say your `class Foo` has a setter  for `@foo`. If some concurrently running code uses that setter to set `@foo` to `nil`, the second call to `Foo#foo` inside the if condition might return `nil` now even though the check passed before.

You can remedy by introducing a local variable  which the compiler can reason about:

```
if foo = a.foo
  puts foo, typeof(foo)
end
```

Comment: The documentation about this behaviour can be found at https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/if_var.html#limitations

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I thought crystal shares same run to completion semantic but seem like it doesn't